# Same html page for different tabs in Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My angular app is routed as following:

```
$stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
  .state('tab', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dotnet', {
      url: '/dotnet',
      views: {
          'tab-dotnet': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dotnet.html',
              controller: 'QuestionsCtrl'
          }
      }
  })

  .state('tab.sql', {
      url: '/sql',
      views: {
          'tab-sql': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/tab-sql.html',
              controller: 'QuestionsCtrl'
          }
      }
  })
```

The above two routes use the same controller but different html pages.
Since both the pages are same, I want to have a single html page in my application instead of two different tab-sql and tab-dotnet pages.
But I will need a differentiation variable to be injected to the controller when selecting the tabs.
Basically I need something like this:

```
  .state('tab.dotnet', {
      url: '/dotnet',
      views: {
          'tab-dotnet': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/tab.html',
              controller: 'QuestionsCtrl',
              type: 'dotnet' // so that i get this type in my Controller
          }
      }
  })

  .state('tab.sql', {
      url: '/sql',
      views: {
          'tab-sql': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/tab.html',
              controller: 'QuestionsCtrl',
              type: 'sql'
          }
      }
  })
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to controllers in a state using `resolve`.

```
  .state('tab.dotnet', {
      url: '/dotnet',
      views: {
          'tab-dotnet': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/tab.html',
              controller: 'QuestionsCtrl',
              resolve: {
                  type: 'dotnet';
              }
          }
      }
  })

  .state('tab.sql', {
      url: '/sql',
      views: {
          'tab-sql': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/tab.html',
              controller: 'QuestionsCtrl',
              resolve: {
                  type: 'sql';
              }
          }
      }
  })
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve